# Implement an Iterable interface with a single item

Tags: java

I have this snippet, where I want to return a single instance `board` to test the solution.  What's a good way to return a single item and exhaust the Iterator?

Placing it an  `final List` and then emptying it an only option?

```
 public Iterable<Board> solution() {
        return new Iterable<Board>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Board> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<Board>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return false; // change this
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Board next() {
                        return board;    // This does not work
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void remove() {

                    }
                };
            }
    };
}
```

Comment: You want to use this in a test and this is not production code?

Comment: Yes, definitely and to understand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you might be overthinking this just a bit, any `Collection` is an `Iterable`, so you could do something as simple as:

```
public Iterable<Board> solution() {
    return Collections.singleton(board);
}
```

Comment: Collections.singleton() would probably be better in this situation.

Comment: @JustinKSU - I agree, much more descriptive on what you're trying to accomplish. I edited that in. Thanks.

Comment: [OP] Sure, thanks! That's one approach. If I don't want to Collections, I will have to do something like what singleton does when iterating. This answer gave me a lead to that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @nickb lead me to see how Singleton implements the iterator and I could come up with the following approach (for my learning /testing).
For production code, I will prefer @nickb's answer.

```
public Iterable<Board> solution() {
    return new Iterable<Board>() {
        /**
         * Returns an iterator over a set of elements of type T.
         *
         * @return an Iterator.
         */
        @Override
        public Iterator<Board> iterator() {

            return new Iterator<Board>() {
                private boolean hasNext = true;
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return hasNext;
                }

                @Override
                public Board next() {
                    if (hasNext) {
                        hasNext = false;
                    }
                    return board;
                }
                @Override
                public void remove() {

                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Note that this still returns the board object on repeated calls to next.  Perhaps you want to have an else clause throwing a NoSuchElementException if hasNext was already false.  Might also be best to have the remove method throw UnsupportedOperationException if you are going to have it do nothing.